# product of inputted numbers

Tags: java, product, between

new here and in java world and I am a student. I just keep getting a wrong product for this question.

Write a Java application that asks the user to input an integer between 1 and 9
inclusive, 10 times, and then prints their product. Your program should use a for loop.
When an integer less than 1 or larger than 9 is input, your application should disregard
it.
You should NOT use logical AND or logical OR operators.

here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class newtest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int counter;
        int product = 1;
        int number;

        System.out.print("Enter number 1-9: ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        for (counter=1; counter<=10; counter++){

        System.out.print("Enter number 1-9: ");
        number = input.nextInt();



        if (number<10){
            if (number>0) product*=number;
                else System.out.println ("number is disregarded");
        }
        else System.out.println ("number is disregarded");


        }   

        product *= number;
        System.out.println (product);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (number<10){


    if (number>0) product*=number;
    else System.out.println ("number is disregarded");}
else System.out.println ("number is disregarded");


}   product *= number;
System.out.println (product);
```

Your problem is here, remove the **product *= number;** that follows the outer if block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. It solved a lot of the problem, but the first number is ignored when I run it.

Comment: Remove the two lines before the `for` statement. They read an integer but never use it.